# Post XML to a URL

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am trying to post an `XMLDocument` to an URL. This is what I have so far:

```
   var uri = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Url"];
   var template = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Template"];
   XmlDocument reqTemplateXml = new XmlDocument();
   reqTemplateXml.Load(template);

   reqTemplateXml.SelectSingleNode("appInfo/appNumber").InnerText = x; 
   reqTemplateXml.SelectSingleNode("appInfo/coappNumber").InnerText = y;

   WebRequest req = null;
   WebResponse rsp = null;
   req = WebRequest.Create(uri);
   req.Method = "POST";
   req.ContentType = "text/xml";
   rsp = req.GetResponse();
```

What I am trying to figure out is how to load this `XmlDocument` to the `WebRequest` object so that it can be posted to that URL.

Comment: will something like this work `rsp.Load(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you need to write to the RequestStream before calling `req.GetResponse()` like this.

```
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        writer.Write(xml);
    }
```

Comment: Finally I am able to debug this. I am not seeing the xml anywhere in the req object. Once this line is executed where should I look for the xml? I am only seeing two keys in req object, Content-type and Host. 

I just want to confirm that xml got added to the object correctly, but can't figure it out. Has been exploring the req object for an hour.

Thanks!

Comment: you won't see it anywhere on the req object in visual studio.  it is written to the stream and I believe you'll mess things up if reset the stream.  if you want to make sure it is getting submitted to the server script correctly, a tool like wireshark might be what you'll want.  often, I'll setup a "local" server script, like my own small asp.net website that just dumps the request to a file.  i'll then post the xml/payload to my local site and examine the file dump.

Comment: What is "xml" (passed to write.Write()) in your code?

Comment: "xml" is a String that, in this case, allegedly is a well formed xml document.